# Parse issue Expected identifier or ')' in _types.h

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Suddenly I'm getting an error in _types.h on the line with typedef. How can I track this down?

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
    typedef __signed char  __int8_t;
#else   /* !__GNUC__ */
```

Answer (score 5):

This is pretty much always caused by a syntax error just prior to whatever included the file with the actual error.

So, have a look in the file that (indirectly) included `_types.h`.   You likely have an unbalanced `(`.

Comment: While neither answer was an exact solution, the both led to resolution. There was a '^' character in front of a comment on the first line of AppController.m

Comment: @Mike: Ah, yes, the old “I didn't realize that editor had focus! Did it… no, it doesn't look like my keystroke went in there…”

Answer (score 4):

Usually these cryptic errors in system header files result from your having other code (perhaps in another header file which was `#import`'ed earlier) that is missing a closing parenthesis. Often whenever you get strange compile errors, you have to look at the lines of code that the compiler encountered *before* the reported line and see if that earlier code was properly terminated.